# Show that $f$ is a Schwartz function if and only if $|\partial^\alpha \phi(x)| \leq C_{\alpha ,N}(1+|x|)^{-N} $

Tags: fourier-transform, schwartz-space, index-notation

Show that a smooth function $f$ is in Schwartz space if only if for all $\alpha\geq 0$ and $N\geq 0$ there is a constant $C_{\alpha,N}$ such that $$|\partial^\alpha \phi(x)| \leq C_{\alpha ,N}(1+|x|)^{-N}$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: What is your definition of the Schwartz space?

Comment: We say $\phi $ in  the Swchartz Space $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if $\phi$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if:  $$ \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}|x^\beta \partial^\alpha \phi(x)| < \infty$$ for all multi-indices $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$.